What is a storage volume on macOS?
I'm trying to understand the concept of a storage volume on macOS.

How is it different from a partition?
Does the term relate specifically to APFS or does it apply to other file systems on other OS as well ?

I saw in the Apple developer documentation an explanation on volumes as a C language struct but it doesn't really explain the concept of volumes and their differences with basic folders : https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf
Any clarification or resources to read would be much appreciated!

I searched for “storage volume” in the PDF and didn’t see any results. I also don’t know what you mean by “basic folder”. Which page are you referring to and what are you aiming at doing with this knowledge?

page 51 "volumes". I don't know what I will do with this knowledge yet. I'm just curious I guess.

Sounds good. My answer for almost everyone here is going to be “ don’t worry - this document isn’t particularly useful for anyone that uses macOS, it’s also not relevant to most programmers” but let me see if there’s a decent link you could start with on Howard Oakley’s eclectic light site to explain at a much higher level, how file systems come together to host folders, files and links to other files and file systems.

An APFS 'container' is analogous to an old-school partition, as it is a fixed-size division of a physical device.
A container ... contains one or more volumes. Multiple volumes within the same container take space from the container on demand as required.
So, in a 500 GB container with one volume, the volume will be as big as the 'used' space; and you could add more volumes in the free space.
The advantage of volumes is that you can add, remove and re-size them dynamically, and that you can create logical volumes spanning multiple partitions (containers).
A volume is a "continuous data space", e.g. one "disk" that would be one icon on your desktop, with its own format e.g. APFS encrypted, APFS case-sensitive.
Logical volumes can create a continuous data space across different containers, such as in Fusion drives or RAID sets.
This is all specific to APFS, though there may be other file systems that use similar concepts. (But you can't mix and match containers and volumes from different file systems/formats.)

A DMG is a "disk image": a complete copy of a disk, as a file, including the file format. It is favoured by developers for supplying software, because it can include multiple files and folders; and there's no real alternative method of downloading a folder (aka 'directory'), because a folder really only exists as part of a file system.

Alright, a volume is a data space. But what makes it fundamentally different from folders in terms of functionality or purpose ?
You mentioned that a volume is analogous to a partition, but I’m curious about the design rationale behind this approach. Why were volumes introduced instead of relying on traditional folders ? What specific problem do volumes solve that folders or partitions couldn’t ? Is there an inherent advantage in terms of performance, security, or flexibility ?

Lastly, why are volumes often used to install macOS applications (e.g. DMG files that mount as volumes) ? Wouldn’t folders suffice for such use cases ?

@DigitalRomance "Folders" are directories within the catalogue of a filing system, and completely different things from disk partitions and volumes. A volume defines an area for one file system. Folders are catalogue entries within a file system. I'll add details to my answer.

"there's no real alternative method of downloading a folder (aka 'directory'), because a folder really only exists as part of a file system" Why not downloading a tarball instead ?

I know a volume and a folder are different. But at the end, they are both used just to store data. So I think the reason why volumes are needed on MacOS instead of folders is not clear.

@DigitalRomance Because you can't use a "folder" at the partition level. A folder has to be inside a file system. A volume represents an entire file system. You can't swap one for the other. A DMG is a copy of a volume, so you can copy it in to other physical devices as a volume.

@DigitalRomance There is all kinds of complexity in data structures in modern computing; and I can't say I understand the need for them all. Abstraction is king. But presumably it serves some need for people who work with them and think about this stuff all day. Ultimately, just accept that these are the definitions of things, and how they work -- and then use them as they are designed.

Volumes basically represent the hardware of the disk (the raw bytes), to make a volume useable you add a filesystem (like APFS or FAT) to it. Folders are a way to structure files within a filesystem. They specifically do not store any data, the data is in files.

If you need an analogy: A disk is a library building, a volume is a room within that building, a filesystem is the indexing system applied in a specific room, a folder is a collection of books stored in that room, and a file is a book (as all analogies it will break as soon as you poke it too much :-)).

Tarballs of course can also be used to distribute files and folders. But they need to be unpacked first, while a DMG is just a volume which can be mounted (a DMG is like a USB stick, just purely digital).

The document you reference is designed for people that will not use the OS or the preferred high-level API. There are maybe 10 to 20 programs that will need that reference or to know the difference between a partition or container or volume stored within either of the above logical abstractions.
Here is the article most people should read. Use APFS and containers so volumes share free space and things like sparse file allocation, copies and other advanced features like snapshots can optimize performance and space available.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/file_system/about_apple_file_system


Many files systems, including HFS Plus, support only a single volume per partition. Because free space can’t be shared across partitions, each volume’s size is set when partitioning the storage device, and each volume can only grow into its available free space. In contrast, Apple File System supports multiple volumes within a single partition, which allows all of those volumes to share their free space. All of the volumes in an Apple File System partition can grow and shrink independently; space that’s freed when one volume shrinks can be used when another volume grows.

Without a very specific programming assignment, no one needs to know what a volume is. Everyone can make backups, choose where an app stores files regardless of the choice of implementation on the physical storage. Volumes allow things like fusion drives, RAID and other optimizations since programs don’t assume they are wiring directly to one piece of hardware direct to the driver. Choose APFS for your logical volumes if at all possible unless you have detailed reasons why you can not (such as legacy hardware or OS).
